# How to handle user authentication in iOS app and PHP/MySQL in the backend

Tags: php, ios, json, authentication

I have a webservice created in PHP/MySQL. I have also created a simple RESTful API for the webservice and what I want is, to create an iOS app (in SWIFT).

What I need is a system for users to login via the iOS app.

If the user, successfully logs in via a web browser, a session starts so it keeps the user authenticated and logged in.

If the user logs in via the iOS app, I know how to validate the user (check email/password) by making a call to my API but I have no idea how I should handle the next step after a successful login. What should be the corresponding "session" for the iOS app?

Please note that I don't want to validate a user via google, facebook or whatever, I only want to validate a user against my database.

Two possible solutions that I have read about are oauth and JWT but their purpose is not clear to me. Especially oauth looks like I should use it if I want users to login to my service via google, fb, etc.

Comment: Why not use something like a session in your app?

Comment: I am not sure if there is something like php's superglobal $_SESSION that will do the job for the app

Comment: What do you think how other apps handle this? They also store some kind of token permanently - or do you have to login to Facebook, Twitter, Instagram,... each and every time you open that app?